# Giving the "attack/defend the flag" command

Tags: battlefield-3

In conquest mode, normally when you are not at the flag cap area, you can give flag attack commands. But when you are inside that area, it doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to give a flag attack command when inside the flag cap area?

Comment: If you are already capping the flag, you cannot give the order. Move out of the capping zone and then you can give it.

Comment: The command only works if you are not capturing the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only give an "Attack the flag" command from outside of the capture zone. You would have to leave the capture zone to give a attack command.

The reason for this is, whether you are giving an "Attack the flag" command or you are inside the flag your teammates are already notified that you are capturing the flag and need support. Once you enter the zone you teammates can see on the HUB and are told that you are capturing, thus it would be repetitive to also command them to attack

Comment: It's a shame that once you are inside the area, you lose the opportunity of gaining extra points by giving the attack/defend command.